# May the repetition of the Amida be said with only 6 people answering Omein but a Minyan is present?

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader, tefillah-betzibbur

My shul would often only have 10 people present but some would daven Shemono Esrei longer and so Chazoras Hashatz would be started  once there were 6 people to answer Omein. Is this correct and if so what is the source, please?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! On the topic of your question: You don't need 10 people to say Amen. You can say a bracha without someone saying Amen. Also, you can even repeat ShEs WITHOUT a Minyan (and say Kedusha), as long as there had been a Minyan before.

Comment: I think the question would be stronger if you'd [edit] into it why you might think you need to wait for ten.

Comment: @Superplane No, you need a minyan for the beginning of shmoneh esrei. It's the stuff after that can rely on the minyan for kedusha. (SA OC 55:3)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for sharing your question. To learn more about the site, consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour).